# NameError: name 'flask' is not defined

Tags: python, flask

I am facing problem while running this line of code in the terminal:

```
$ sudo python app.py
```

And  the Traceback is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "app.py", line 7, in <module>

   APP = flask.Flask(__name__)

NameError: name 'flask' is not defined
```

sudo pip install flask

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): flask in 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Werkzeug>=0.7 in 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from flask)

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Jinja2>=2.4 in 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from flask)

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): 

itsdangerous>=0.21 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from flask)

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): markupsafe in 

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from Jinja2>=2.4->flask)

Cleaning up...
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try installing `Flask` using `pip install flask`

Comment: You need to *import* the module.

Comment: It seems like you havent imported or installed the flask module try adding to the top of the program import flask or type into cmd or terminal pip install flask

Answer (score 9, accepted):

if flask is not installed:

```
pip install flask
```

then

```
import flask
```

Answer (score 10):

**Answer for your question is :**

1. If your import statement is like this -

   ```
   from flask import Flask

   app = flask.Flask(name)
   ```

   then it will give error:

   > NameError: name 'flask' is not defined
2. If your import statement is like this -

   import flask

   app = Flask(name)

   then it will give error:

   > NameError: name 'Flask' is not defined

*** * Solution for above errors - * ***

1. Please install flask through `pip install flask` if not installed.
2. Below code will solve your problem.

   ```
   from flask import Flask
   app = Flask(name)
   ```

   OR

   ```
   import flask
   app = flask.Flask(name)
   ```

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I already had flask installed.
I got the same error, but this worked for me:

```
import flask
from flask import Flask
```